# use Jquery next button to bring up next Club

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I have a button that, when pressed, is supposed to bring up the next club to the DOM without refreshing. It works for the next club once, but won't work after that. I need to somehow change the club id on the button to allow the api to get the next's club information. I'm not sure what the best way to do that is. Any ideas?

```
 <div class="container-fluid">
  <h1>Your Club</h1>
  <br>
    <div id="club-info">
    <h2 class="club-name"><%= @club.name %></h2>
    <br>
    <h2 class="club-brand"><%= @club.brand %></h2>
    </div>
  <br>
  <button class="next-club" data-id="<%= @club.id %>">Next Club</button>
  <br>
  <br>
  <%= link_to "See all of your clubs", club_path %>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
  $(function() {
    $('.next-club').click(function() {
      var id = $(this).data("id");
      $('#club-info').html('')
      $.get('/clubs/' + id + '/next', function(data, status) {
        $('#club-info').append(`<h2>${data.name}</h2>` + 
          `<br>` + 
          `<h2>${data.brand}</h2>`);
      })
    }) 
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On get request success you could add

```
$('.next-club').data('id', data.id);
```

The above would use Jquery .data to change the id sent. (https://api.jquery.com/data/)

Comment: This is perfect. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign new id to button after success and make sure dynamically updates that button data attribute.

Check `$that.data` part where assigning new data id. if using friendly-id make it.

```
$(document).on('click', '.next-club', function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   var id = $(this).data("id");
   var $that = $(this);         

   $.get('/clubs/' + id + '/next', function(data, status) {
        if(status == 'success'){
            $('#club-info').html('')
            $('#club-info').append(`<h2>${data.name}</h2>` + 
                   `<br>` + 
                   `<h2>${data.brand}</h2>`);
            $that.data('id', data.id); #assign new id
        }
   })
}
```